# Element does not expand on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm kind of a newbie coder and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I want to make an element expand when I click a line of text, but it simply is just not expanding and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

For reference, this is the [site or info card I'm working on](https://verse.mnho.repl.co/).

The text that says "click me" is what I'm trying to make expand said element.

I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this.

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("expander")) {
    $(this).removeClass("expander");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("expander");
  }
});
```

```css
.expander {
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #242424; background-color: rgba(33, 33, 31, 2); border-top: double #831407 0px; border-left: double #831407 0px; padding: 10px; width: 159px; overflow:auto; position:relative; center: 20px; top: 20px;">
  <font face="times new roman" color="#831407" size="1">
    <div align="center" style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #831407, 0px 0px 0px #3C4595;">
      <font size="2px"><img src="https://yokai.crd.co/assets/images/gallery03/4246c620.gif?v=b4df531c" style="width:15px;height:15px"> <b>mikey</b> <img src="https://yokai.crd.co/assets/images/gallery03/58ed5769.gif?v=b4df531c" style="width:15px;height:15px"></font>
      <font face="times new roman" color="#831407" size="1"><br><b>they</b> | <b>adult</b> | <b>isfp</b></font>
      <br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="expander">click me
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet demo I created to show the problem. I'm not sure I understand your goal since you apparently want to expand the clicked element.

Comment: Protip 2: Put your styles in CSS, not in your HTML. It's a huge pain to work that way.

Comment: And 3: `align` is an obsolete attribute. Be sure you're following modern documentation, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: So is [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: you reinvented `toggleClass()`

Comment: I guess I'd suggest that you start fresh using modern HTML. There's a lot not right about what's up there.

Comment: Minus the missing closing div tag, your code works. So unclear what is not working. jquery is adding and removing the class. Hard to tell that the height changes since the element has nothing after it.

Comment: wauggg i'm sorry for all the trouble guys. what i wanted to fix was the "click me" line of text on the site that i linked. i figured that once i clicked said text, the box element would appear, but it doesn't. i guess that's what i'm stuck on. but, thank you for all the help and advice, i'll look into fixing it or just restarting

Comment: WAIT. NEVER MIND LMFJSADKSJSD i fixed it  THANK YOU ALL.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [.slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) method of `jquery`.
Here is an example :

```js
$(".expander").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".expanded").slideToggle();
    //open up the expanded- toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.

});
```

```css
.expanded{
  height: 100px;
  background : green;
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expander"><button>click to expand</button></div>
<div class="expanded"></div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the clicked element to be expanded

Comment: Is that? Oh I couldn't understand the question properly @RohitGupta